# Searching a UITableView: cell images won't change

Tags: ios

I am filtering an array in this way to provide content to my table view:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
filteredTableData = [[allFileNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}
```

when I change the text in the search bar, the search is done and I see cells with similar names popping up. However the cell.imageview.image seems not to be changing. I get the correct title label with the image that before the search was in that cell... Why does this happen?

Comment: Show the code related to the cell configuration.

Comment: I had a similar issue.
Turns out I was adding subviews in configureCell without removing the previously added ones for re-used cells.